# Getting days of current week using kotlinx-datetime KMM

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, kotlinx-datetime

How can I get the dates of the current week using kotlinx.datetime KMM library?

eg. I want to get a list of current week's date like:

(*"Monday, 07"*, *"Tuesday, 08"*, *"Wednesday, 09"*, ... )

This is a similar impementation using [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar):

```kotlin
fun getDaysOfWeek(): Array<String?> {
        val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEEEE\ndd", Locale.getDefault())
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.firstDayOfWeek = Calendar.MONDAY
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY)

        val days = arrayOfNulls<String>(7)
        for (i in 0..6) {
            days[i] = dateFormat.format(calendar.time)
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        }

        return days
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
val today = Clock.System.now().toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.currentSystemDefault()).date
val days = mutableListOf<LocalDate>()
val firstWeekDay = today.daysShift(-DayOfWeek.values().indexOf(today.dayOfWeek))
for (i in 0 until DayOfWeek.values().count()) {
    days.add(firstWeekDay.daysShift(i))
}
val dayStrings = days.map { "${it.dayOfWeek}, ${it.dayOfMonth}" }
println("$dayStrings")
```

```
fun LocalDate.daysShift(days: Int): LocalDate = when {
    days < 0 -> {
        minus(DateTimeUnit.DayBased(-days))
    }
    days > 0 -> {
        plus(DateTimeUnit.DayBased(days))
    }
    else -> this
}
```